# Meaning of battery name

Tags: batteries

I'm currently working on making a battery I salvaged from a mowing robot usable. It doesn't have a datasheet or anything, since it was made specifically for the robot and wasn't intended for consumers. That's why I can only use measurements and the sticker on the front to get any data like voltage or capacity. I get most things on this sticker, 2 of them however, I don't understand the meaning of.

First, in the same line that gives me Voltage and Capacity, there is a seemingly random number. Does anyone know what it means? Probably nothing actually concerning the technical stats of the battery, but I just want to make sure.

18.5V / 2.1 Ah / 38.85 WH    ***1546***

Then there is the thing I can only assume is the name of the battery: **5INR 19/66 Rechargable Lithium-Ion Battery**. I know it might just be a name, but INR for example, specifies the type of said battery as a **lithium manganese nickel battery**. I don't know if the numbers mean anything, but again, I just want to make sure.

Here's the entire thing.
[image]
https://www.trgo-agencija.hr/baterija-automower-husqvarna-105-305-586-57-62-01.html

Comment: It's likely a part number for whatever brand that battery is, though I don't have proof of this to really say.

Comment: No, the part-number is already given somewhere else. I've added an image to help with the question. Interestingly the specific number is different for this battery. Maybe it's some sort of ID?

Comment: It could be a time stamp in the form YYMM documenting the year and month of production. ICs have such numbers, too. Is it plausible that your batteries are produced in 2015?

Comment: The robot I got it from was a 2015 edition. Definitely possible.

Comment: Well now that you've edited your question, I definitely agree with Justin's answer :) When you ask questions on here, you should really provide as much information as possible. I should have reminded you of this earlier.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it is a date code, probably 2 digit year and 2 digit week. The one in the picture says "Made in PRC 2015", and the code is 1546, so it was probably made in the 46th week of 2015.

Comment: You're probably right, thank you!